# How can I simplify/more readable this by using calls to InOrder (code below)

Tags: java, if-statement, return, boolean, conditional-statements

How can I simplify/more readable this by using calls to InOrder (code below).
The aim of the code is to check if a Rectangle contains a Point.
Below is the code for firstly the Rectangle class, and further below is the InOrder class.
I am having trouble finding a way to make the code more readable and I want to simplify it the best way possible.

```
// Construct a rectangle from two arbitrary points
public class Rectangle {
private int x1;
private int y1;
private int x2;
private int y2;

public Rectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
this.x1 = x1;
this.y1 = y1;
this.x2 = x2;
this.y2 = y2;
}

public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
if(x1 <= x2) {
    if(x1 <= x && x <= x2) {
    if(y1 <= y2) {
        return y1 <= y && y <= y2;
    } else {
        return y2 <= y && y <= y1;
    }
    }
} else {
    if(x2 <= x && x <= x1) {
    if(y1 <= y2) {
        return y1 <= y && y <= y2;
    } else {
        return y2 <= y && y <= y1;
    }       
    }       
}

return false;
}
}



public class InOrder {
//Don't change this
public boolean OutOfOrder(int n1, int n2, int n3) {
return (n1 > n2) || (n2 > n3);
}

//The original and messy InOrder, leave this as an example of what not to do
public boolean inOrder(int n1, int n2, int n3) {
if (n2 > n1) {
  if (n3 > n2) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
} else if (n2 == n1) {
  if (n3 == n1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
} else {
  return false;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `inOrder` may be refactored like this:

```java
// InOrder
public static boolean inOrder(int min, int n, int max) {
    if (n > min) {
        return max > n;
    } else if (n == min) {
        return n == max;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It would be fine to make `inOrder` static to avoid unnecessary creation of `InOrder` instances.

Then `Rectangle::contains` may be refactored to define min and max values and then reuse modified `InOrder::inOrder`:

```java
// class Rectangle
public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
    int minx = x1 < x2 ? x1 : x2;
    int maxx = x1 > x2 ? x1 : x2;
    int miny = y1 < y2 ? y1 : y2;
    int maxy = y1 > y2 ? y1 : y2;
    return InOrder.inOrder(minx, x, maxx) && InOrder.inOrder(miny, y, maxy);
}
```

It is also possible to use static imports for `Math.min` / `Math.max` methods as well as `inOrder`, then `Rectangle::contains` may be rewritten as one-liner:

```
import static java.lang.Math.min;
import static java.lang.Math.max;
import static InOrder.inOrder;

// class Rectangle
public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
    return inOrder(min(x1, x2), x, max(x1, x2)) && inOrder(min(y1, y2), y, max(y1, y2));
}
```